# Bundle Jre with Install4J

Tags: install4j

I have downloaded JRE (jre-x64-1.8.0_40.zip) using Maven Dependency.
I want to Bundle this Jre to install4J. 
When I am trying to bundle this, during building it is showing error as FileNotFoundException and looking for File jre-x64-1.8.0_40.zip.tar.gz.

How can I bundle jre zip?

If not, does install4j provide feature to convert file type?

Comment: Can you not just download the .tar.gz file from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jre-8u40-oth-JPR

Answer (score 2):

You can create install4j JRE bundles **from installed JREs** by invoking  *Project->Create a JRE Bundle* from the main menu or by using the `createbundle` command line utility.

It is not possible to directly convert a ZIP with a JRE or an archive downloaded from the Oracle web site into a JRE bundle that is usable by install4j. You have to install the JRE first in any case.

**This has changed with install4j 8.** For details, see section "JRE bundle format" on https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/jreBundles.html.

Comment: While creating install4j JRE bundles from installed JREs using install4J IDE, the bundle jre is stored in Install4j location of in my local system. I have created compiler variable to point to that path. When I pushed the changes to bamboo server, build is failing as JRE is not found.

Comment: If there's no JRE at all on the build server, you need to install one because otherwise the build toolchain will not even start. If it's just install4j complaining, you need to provide the bundles on that machine, at the location that the install4j project expects them (you may have to adapt the latter so that it will work both locally and on the build server).